# how to deepcopy when pickling is not possible

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, pickle, deep-copy

I'm trying to deepcopy a dictionary in Python 3.4 but some of the values are not "pickable", i.e. when I try to deepcopy the dictionary, it raises a RuntimeError exception

```
*** RuntimeError: Pickling of "DataObject" instances is not enabled (http://www.boost.org/libs/python/doc/v2/pickle.html)
```

What would be the best option to deepcopy the dictionary?

So far, I'm recursively iterating through the dictionary and creating a new one but I would like to know if there's a more robust and elegant solution.

Note: I cannot modify DataObject structure to support pickling.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add copy functions to the [`copyreg` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copyreg.html) to handle types that cannot be pickled:

```
import copyreg

pickle_dataobject(do):
    return DataObject, (do.arg1, do.arg2)

copyreg.pickle(DataObject, pickle_dataobject)
```

The idea is that you return a constructor and the arguments that are to be passed to the constructor to re-create the original value.

The `copy.deepcopy()` function then uses the above `pickle_dataobject()` to obtain a copy whenever `ob is DataObject` is true (the class is looked up in the `copyreg.dispatch_table` dictionary that `copyreg.pickle()` adds your function to).

Comment: I can see this is the right way to do it. Sadly in my case, I don't have good visibility of all the DataObject arguments. I work with some "special" (annoying) swig interfaces of C++ libraries that have lots of issues like that. I can't see how could I use this method without being able to list all the arguments.
That said, I think this is the way to go so I'll mark it as the right answer.

Comment: @zom-pro: well, how do you create new instances now? Is it perhaps a another class that contains these things that you need to hook into instead? The idea is that you leave everything to `copy.deepcopy()` still, but teach it how to copy specific types without having to alter those types directly. But if these objects are created as internal data structures for some container class, teach `copyreg` about the container class instead.

Comment: with Python 2.7 copy_reg can be used. The copy_reg module has been renamed to copyreg in Python 3.